# How do I create a list like the one below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series on URL's that I need to replicate as follows.

```
https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=*1205*
```

The 1205 is variable the final outputs need to look like

```
"https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205#taxpage1"
................................................#taxpage2"
................................................#taxpage3
................................................#taxpage4
```

and so on. I have a list of URL's with out the `"#taxpage"` portion and list of how many tax pages each should have. I want to generate list of all the possible pages for each URL. Thank you for any help....completely new to coding and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.format` to add the `#taxpage` number in a list comprehension

```
>>> s = r'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205#taxpage{}'
>>> [s.format(i) for i in range(1, 5)]
    ['https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205#taxpage1',
     'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205#taxpage2',
     'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205#taxpage3',
     'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205#taxpage4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using list comprehension:

```
In [1]: urls = ['https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205',
                'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1206']

In [2]: ["{}#taxpage{}".format(url, page_num) for page_num in xrange(1, 4) for url in urls]
Out[2]: 
['https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205#taxpage1',
 'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1206#taxpage1',
 'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205#taxpage2',
 'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1206#taxpage2',
 'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1205#taxpage3',
 'https://wipp.edmundsassoc.com/Wipp/?wippid=1206#taxpage3']
```